# Process JSON conditionally in python

Tags: python, json

I am new to python and trying to process the JSON from [here](https://opendata.ecdc.europa.eu/covid19/casedistribution/json/)

I managed to get the data into python and also managed to extract some part from the JSON with:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import json
req = urlopen("http://opendata.ecdc.europa.eu/covid19/casedistribution/json/")
response = req.read()
data = json.loads(response)

deaths = [i["deaths"] for i in data["records"]]

print(deaths)
```

How can I add a condition like for instance `i["geoId"] == "AF"` such that `deaths` only contains the deaths from Afghanistan?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the condition at the end of the list comprehension:

```
deaths = [i["deaths"] for i in data["records"] if i["geoId"] == "AF"]
```